# Saving the custom model

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have a built a custom  model and planned to store the model in \ S3 which suits my project.

We have 2 different ways to save a model

```
nlp.to_bytes()
nlp.to_disk()
```

`nlp.to_disk()` needs a path in the argument. So I choose to go with `nlp.to_bytes()`,

Code:

```
to_bytes_model = custom_nlp.to_bytes()
In: type(to_bytes_model) 
Out: bytes

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')    
s3.Bucket('customregex').upload_file('to_bytes_model','new_folder')
```

The above code for boto3 gives me error saying there is no file `to_bytes_model`

Do need help on saving the nlp model directly to S3. Thanks.

Comment: you are using wrong method use `upload_fileobj()`. `upload_file()` takes file path as first argument here you are passing `bytes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`to_bytes_model` is an in-memory object. It is not written to a file on disk. Using `upload_file()` which looks for a file on disk based on the name of the file you pass in. See the documentation [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file).

One way to do this is to use `nlp.to_disk()` followed by using some library to create zip/tar and then use `upload_file()` to upload the zip/tar. If you wish to skip the zip/tar you will need iterate over all the files in the folder to upload them one by one. I personally prefer option 1.

Comment: so by the first option you mean, i need to save the model first in the local and then zip it and then upload it to s3 ?

Comment: yes, save using nlp.to_disk() then zip it then upload the zip to s3.

Comment: The model is ran in the production environment which keeps updating .. so there is no way I can go save it in the local, it has to directly go into S3

Comment: By local I meant whichever machine your script runs on. It need not be your machine. If this runs on production then that is the local I meant.